# C++ File Stops Reading After First Line

Tags: c++, string, sockets, plist, ifstream

I am trying to send the contents of a plist file over a socket. `userPlist` is a `ifstream` and the file opens correctly and as it should. But when it is run it only sends `bplist00?` over the socket and then stops. Why would that be? Here is my source code:

```
if (userPlist.is_open()) {
    string line;
    int i;
    int sizeOfPlist;
    char plistChar[128];
    while (getline(userPlist, line)) {                    
        sizeOfPlist = line.size();
        for (i = 0; i <= sizeOfPlist; i++)
        {
            plistChar[i] = line[i];
        }
        line = "\0";
        send(sock, plistChar, strlen(plistChar), 0);
        for (i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
            plistChar[i] = '\0';
        }
        send(sock, "\n", strlen("\n"), 0);
    }
}
```

If anybody has any suggestions or advice, that would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: strlen(plistChar) - where does the terminating null come from first time around?

Comment: @MartinJames I'm sorry I don't know what you mean.

Comment: In C, strings have to be terminated by '\0'. You are using a C function for strings, strlen(). It will count how many characters it finds before hitting '\0'. You never put a '\0' in your C string (plistChar), so all sorts of bad stuffs could be happening. Also you are indexing a C++ string one-past-the-end because of your loop termination condition. It might have a '\0' by sheer luck, but it's also undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion: If your file stops reading after the first line then my guess is that it is an issue with your while loop - have you checked to see if the while loop is executing more than once? Use breakpoints in the debugger to do this. I don't think getline() is a valid conditional check but it's worth checking

Comment: It only executes twice

Comment: But it hangs on the second while loop

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You have one while loop in your code snippet. Are you saying that on the second while loop iteration the program doesn't end or unexpectedly ends. OR are you saying that your program goes into an infinite loop in a second while loop(perhaps one that you aren't showing us) How many times do you expect to iterate through the while loop?

Comment: An infinite loop, and i guess this program doesn't really matter anymore because the file I'm trying to read is a plist and it gets messed up when I try to view it in plain text, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

1. Your for loop is executing an extra time because you're using `<=` instead of `<`:

   ```
   for (i = 0; i <= sizeOfPlist; i++)
   //            ^^
   ```
2. `pListChar` is not null-terminated by the time you send it to the socket. You need this line:

   ```
   pListChar[sizeOfPlist] = '\0';

   send(sock, plistChar, strlen(plistChar), 0);
   ```

   You also don't need `line = "\0";`.

Comment: Turns out the file had null characters in it but thanks for the answer